# Do Hindu texts talk about how to respond to ideology which is against Hinduism?

Tags: scripture

To further my question [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11682/what-are-the-reasons-for-anti-hindu-violence-in-modern-india), I ask this related question. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-Hinduism) wiki article talks in great length about anti-Hinduism and related events. Do Hindu texts about how to respond to such ideology?

Comment: Love comes reflected back as love. Hate breeds more fierce hate.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda: Same question here, why do you consider this question as inappropriate for the site?

Comment: Didn't say it was inappropriate for this site. As Buddha once said, if a person offers you a gift and you do not accept it, who retains the gift? Answer: the person offering the gift. In other words, if you do not accept the hate that is being offered to you, it remains with the person that was trying to give it. And as Vivekananda said, Love comes reflected back as love, hate breeds more fierce hate. Offer love in return for hate.

Comment: Hinduphobia or Anti-Hinduism sounds modern idea. I don't think you'll find any such things from Hindu texts/scriptures. Instead you can find for Adharma which I think similar.

Comment: In the middle ages, Indians had encountered Greeks and Chinese and later in 13th cent. Muslims. I'm sure someone might have written about it.